# Trying to find a recursive solution to an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have an infinite series that I need to write a function for (in Python) to calculate. To do so, I need to find the recursive definition of the formula, which I am having trouble with.

$$\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}$$

So far I have figured out the numerator to be

$$ t_{n+1} = t_n \times -z^2 $$

and the $n!$ turns into $(n+1)$, but I have no idea what the rest of the denominator turns into.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write
$$
a_{n} = \frac{(-1)^{n} z^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}=\frac{z}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{\left(-z^2\right)^{n}}{n!}
$$
recursively, you can use $a_0=z$ and
$$
a_{n}=\frac{1-2n}{2n+1}\cdot\frac{z^2 a_{n-1}}{n}.
$$
for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I made the mistake of just looking at the denominator to try and figure out the coefficient, since most simpler series are like that.

Comment: Be careful when computing many terms. Also, to minimize rounding error you must start adding with the small ones. Also, the alternating terms guarantee numerical problems here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks awfully familiar... start with:
$$
exp(- z^2) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n z^{2 n}}{n!}
$$
Integrate with respect to $z$, and you have your terms. But that integral is essentially the error function, which has good implementations in the math library (I believe it is even mandated by POSIX).